# SFINAE to limit instantiated type to std::chrono::duration types

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to do something like

```
template <typename T>
class TemporalAlarmDelay<T, std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<std::chrono::duration< , >, T>::value, T>::type>
{
public:
    explicit TemporalAlarmDelay(T delay)
        : mDelay(delay)
    {

    }

private:
    T mDelay;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point mTriggerTime;
};


int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    TemporalAlarmDelay<std::chrono::nanoseconds> nanosecondDelay;   // this should work
    TemporalAlarmDelay<std::chrono::milliseconds> millisecondDelay; // this should work 
    TemporalAlarmDelay<std::chrono::seconds> secondDelay;           // this should work
    TemporalAlarmDelay<int> failDelay;                              // fail to instantiate
}
```

The intent is to limit to types of `std::chrono::duration` (e.g `std::chrono::milliseconds`, `std::chrono::seconds`). What is the best way to go about this? As per my example, I was thinking I could use `std::is_base_of`, but I now realize that the helper types (e.g. `std::chrono::milliseconds`, `std::chrono::seconds` etc) do not use inheritance - derrr, what a silly thought.

Comment: This sounds a bit like a XY-problem. What do you want to achive?

Comment: No it doesn't, I explicitly state what I want to do. I even provide an example of how I want to instantiate. Thanks for your helpful input :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And for the very simplest solution to your problem...

```
#include <chrono>

class TemporalAlarmDelay
{
public:
    explicit TemporalAlarmDelay(std::chrono::steady_clock::duration delay)
        : mDelay(delay)
    {

    }

private:
    std::chrono::steady_clock::duration   mDelay;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point mTriggerTime;
};


int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    TemporalAlarmDelay nanosecondDelay{1ns};   // this works
    TemporalAlarmDelay millisecondDelay{1ms};  // this works
    TemporalAlarmDelay secondDelay{1s};        // this works
    TemporalAlarmDelay failDelay{1};           // compile-time error
}
```

Comment: yes definitely the simplest.. I definitely did not keep simple things simple. I will definitely update the implementation, because your design just make sense! Thanks for your efforts with chrono!

Answer (score 2):

You can use template specialization:

```
template <typename T>
class TemporalAlarmDelay
{
    ~TemporalAlarmDelay() = delete; // prevent instantiation
};

template <typename R, typename P>
class TemporalAlarmDelay<std::chrono::duration<R, P>>
{
    // your code
};
```

@Jarod42 suggests that you can even get away with:

```
template <typename> class TemporalAlarmDelay;
```

instead of the first four lines above.

Comment: I would even omit generic definition.

Comment: @Jarod42: you mean just declare the template ? 10+ years of C++ and I have never tried this. Good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can create traits:

```
template <typename T> struct is_chrono_duration : std::false_type {};

template <typename R, typename P>
struct is_chrono_duration<std::chrono::duration<R, P>> : std::true_type {};
```

and then:

```
template <typename T>
class TemporalAlarmDelay
{
    static_assert(is_chrono_duration<T>::value, "!");
    // your code
};
```

Comment: This didn't work :(
`C:\IMC_System\FastBuildDev\PI.cpp(382): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::chrono::milliseconds' to 'TemporalAlarmDelay<std::chrono::nanoseconds>' 
    C:\IMC_System\FastBuildDev\PI.cpp(382): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous`

Comment: @tuskcode - doesn't work because your class require an argument for the constructor but, in your example, you pass zero arguments to it; just to try if works, give a default value to your constructor (by example: `explicit TemporalAlarmDelay(T delay = T{}) : mDelay(delay)`).

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from the Jarod42's `is_chrono_duration` (well... copying it, to be honest), a possible SFINAE based (over a default boolean value) solution

```
template <typename T, bool = is_chrono_duration<T>::value>
class TmpAlrD;

template <typename T>
class TmpAlrD<T, true>
 {
   // ...
 };
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <chrono>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>
struct is_chrono_duration : std::false_type
 { };

template <typename R, typename P>
struct is_chrono_duration<std::chrono::duration<R, P>> : std::true_type
 { };

template <typename T, bool = is_chrono_duration<T>::value>
class TmpAlrD;

template <typename T>
class TmpAlrD<T, true>
 {
   public:
      explicit TmpAlrD(T delay = T{}) : mDelay(delay)
       { }

   private:
      T mDelay;

      std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point mTriggerTime;
 };

int main ()
 {
   TmpAlrD<std::chrono::nanoseconds>  nsDelay; // compile
   TmpAlrD<std::chrono::milliseconds> msDelay; // compile 
   TmpAlrD<std::chrono::seconds>      sDelay;  // compile
   //TemporalAlarmDelay<int>                   // compilation error     
 }
```