# Concept that models only the std::chrono duration types

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono, c++-concepts

Can I write a concept that recognizes any of the standard `std::chrono` duration types without just listing them all explicitly like:

```
template <typename T>
concept IsStdDuration =
std::same_as<T, std::chrono::nanoseconds> || std::same_as<T, std::chrono::microseconds> || ...
```

Yes, I know I could use a  "any of these types" helper concept to reduce the boilerplate, but I'm wondering if I can avoid listing them all explicitly in the first place.

Comment: Do you know what those types are?  (If you do the pattern may already be ruled out; if you don't the pattern might be what you want)

Answer (score 5):

`<chrono>` implementations have to do this operation too.  They typically do it as traits instead of concepts, but it is easy to implement the trait and then have a concept reference the trait.

[Here is the llvm implementation:](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/2e999b7dd1934a44d38c3a753460f1e5a217e9a5/libcxx/include/__chrono/duration.h#L32-L45)

```
template <class _Tp>
struct __is_duration : false_type {};

template <class _Rep, class _Period>
struct __is_duration<duration<_Rep, _Period> > : true_type  {};

template <class _Rep, class _Period>
struct __is_duration<const duration<_Rep, _Period> > : true_type  {};

template <class _Rep, class _Period>
struct __is_duration<volatile duration<_Rep, _Period> > : true_type  {};

template <class _Rep, class _Period>
struct __is_duration<const volatile duration<_Rep, _Period> > : true_type  {};
```

Your version should not use the `__` prefix, which is reserved for the std::implemenation.

Comment: You can avoid duplication here by using `remove_cv`

Comment: @Mikdore This will require additional level of indirection.

Answer (score 2):

Without using a helper, you can pattern match a nested lambda call:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept IsStdDuration = requires {
    []<class Rep, class Period>(std::type_identity<std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>>){}(
        std::type_identity<T>());
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending from the traits approach in a related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47086645/6311962, you can define a concept using trait types:

```
template <class _Tp>
struct is_chrono_duration : std::false_type {};

template <class _Rep, class _Period>
struct is_chrono_duration<std::chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename _Tp>
concept chrono_duration = is_chrono_duration<_Tp>::value;
```

Comment: What about cv-qualifiers?